# Can the values of the targets be NAN on multiple outputs neural network on lasagne?

Tags: theano, lasagne

Having a dataset for which 3 different outcomes exist, but there might be missing values for these outcomes, can neural networks training in lasagne deal with this NAN or should a neural network be trained for each outcome (where NAN cases are removed from training)?

Lets say we have the following targets:

```
1,2,3
NAN,1,5
1,NAN,2
0,NAN,NAN
```

Please note that imputation is not what I am interest in.

Comment: your nan inputs will be propagated to all your results.

Comment: No, you cannot calculate a gradient with nans. Just multiply the cost function with 0 wherever you don't have information, so the gradient will be 0 and won't get backpropagated.